# Using Youtube v3 Api key

Tags: c#, youtube-api, windows-phone

I'm trying to build an youtube based app, and I'm using version 3.0 of Youtube Data API, I did register the app in Google Cloud Console and I did obtain an API Key. After that I tried to test it in a console application in Visual Studio 2010, I used a `WebClient` to retrieve a video search using this URL
"https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=YouTube+Data+API&type=video&key={MY API KEY}"

I learned this from [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/sample_requests). I used both a Browser key and a Server key, but the server sends back an error saying the request is incorrect.

So can anyone point me to the error I'm making?

PS: I am trying to make a windows phone app, and before doing so I wanted to learn how to manipulate the Youtube API first, this is why I am testing in a console application

Comment: You're supposed to use a server key. Did you enable the API? This video shows you how to do it for the old version, but the concept still applies (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Im69kzhpR3I&list=PLhBgTdAWkxeB-zCekGukAo0DzmpwBiua2&index=1)

Comment: Yes I did before posting the question

Answer (score 4):

Make sure that the YouTube Data API is enabled in the [Google Developer Console](https://cloud.google.com/console/project). It should look something like this:

[image]

The key you are looking for is the server key, which looks something like this:

[image]

(I've truncated my key for security purposes). I now copy and paste this into my browser window:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=YouTube+Data+API&type=video&key=YOURKEYWOULDGOHERE
```

This works for me. Start here to verify that the key is working and that the API has been enabled correctly. I suggest using the API client, because some API calls will require an OAuth 2.0 access token, not the simple API key (search API requires regular simple API key).

Comment: Thanks for your post.  I have no idea why they named it a server key instead of a client key.  Created quite a bit of confusion for me since I'm running a desktop client app.