# youtube api application key validation

Tags: youtube-api

Does anyone know if the youtube api has an endpoint or other api to call to verify if an app key is valid? The only option I can think of is to make any call to the api and check if an error is returned for example a search :

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&id=zzzz&key=xxxxxx
```

A seperate endpoint that provides perhaps the quota for a key would be useful. Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may refer in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21117446/5832311). As stated in your post, you may request a call to the API to verify that your key is working.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=YouTube+Data+API&type=video&key=APIKEY
```

You may also check this thread: [How do I catch an invalid API key for google maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4428915/how-do-i-catch-an-invalid-api-key-for-google-maps)

> Google does not offer an external method of checking the Google Maps API key. Hence you cannot query some service with e.g. "Is this code valid `abcde1234`" and get a `TRUE`/`FALSE` response.
>
> There is a discussion on [how the Maps API key is generated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2256305/how-does-google-maps-secure-their-api-key-how-to-make-something-similar). But I suggest you look at a post from [Mike Williams about the `GValidateKey` function](http://groups.google.com/group/Google-Maps-API/browse_thread/thread/c84f3b3dfd277e9b/f9e3c5ad3cbda4d7?pli=1). This is the function actually doing the magic validation - what it exactly does, like creating a hash from your Google account / domain - we don't know.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. I just wanted to clarify an additional point; there is also no API endpoint to return current quota usage as it appears in the dashboard page.